# tidy google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm a bit of a nut about clean HTML, is there a tidier way to implement Google analytics? I feel like if I move it to a .js file it won't work.

Comment: Yeah, sounds a bit nutty.  On a serious note -- is it that bad, the whole 4-5 lines of it?

Comment: HA - I really like to have my HTML, CSS, JS, and code for that matter all tidy and separate from one another. I mean if its not possible, fine. but there goes all the fun of looking over my beautiful source.

Comment: It's good to be precise, neat, and through.  You would most likely like this: http://css-tricks.com/examples/CleanCode/Beautiful-HTML.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move it to an external js file and it will work just fine. In fact, maybe you want it to load after your dom completes loading. It's up to you. If you want to make sure, install wireshark and watch the connection get made to analytics.google.com .

wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org/